# converting datagridview column valuetype to string from char in C#

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn

I have an IEnumerable List, and a datagridview is being fed at runtime by this list.

```
i.e. datagridviewBindingSource.DataSource = myList;
     datagridview.DataSource = datagridviewBindingSource;
```

In this list, all columns are of type "string" but two columns **"Status"** and **"Area"** which contains **values of type 'char'.**

> Status can have values = { 'O' , 'C'}   (Open and Close) ,  Area can
>   have values = {'I','F','R'}  (In-Process, Final, Receive}

Now, at runtime, I want to display:

> Open instead of O
>
> Close instead of C
>
> In-Process instead of I

and so on...

I am doing this :

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    if (c.HeaderText == "Status")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(c.ValueType.ToString());
                        c.ValueType = typeof(string);
                    }
                }
                foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
                    {
                        if (c.Value == null)
                        {
                            c.Value = "";
                        }
                        if (c.Value.GetType() == typeof(char))
                        {
                            //c.ValueType = typeof(string);
                            if (c.Value.ToString() == "O")
                            {
                                c.Value = "Open";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Program compiles but at runtime throws an exception as shown in image.[image]

Any help is appreciated.

I am using Dapper to query my database, and in the class "Area" and "Status" columns are defined as char, so as in Database. So changing their datatype while the app is distributed on client machines is not an option for me. I just want to handle it in the "frontend" logic.

Comment: In which method is that `foreach` loop contained?

Comment: The Method(`GetData()`) containing this piece of code is used to get data from database and then do filtering etc on it and it is being called from constructor.

Comment: How do you guarantee that `dataGridView1` has data (e.g."O") before you enter the for loop?

Comment: While troubleshooting this problem, I made sure of it. Datagrid does have data. and I guess that is why exception says `System.String` can not be converted to `System.Char`, because it can not process data.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to replace the value of 'O' with "Open" which is a string. Hence, the system is throwing the error. A better way would be if you could add a new cell altogether to that row and assign this string value to it, mark this new cell as visible and bind it to your grid, and then mark the char cell as invisible. That way you'd have both the original char value with you as well as a way to display the string in the grid.

Comment: That is an excellent idea!! One of the use of this datagridview is to export in an excel file, so adding a new cell and then excluding the other one while exporting adds up.

Comment: Sorry, but what i am really looking for is to convert the column type to string or something less tedious that adding a cell and excluding cell while exporting. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Your comment seemed like you got an idea on how to proceed. Well, if converting the column type to string is an option, that should have been done in the first place and this post wouldn't even be necessary. Also, the values should have been passed as "open", "close", "in-process", etc. instead of 'O', 'C', 'I' so you dont have to convert again. Any reason why the column was not defined as string before?

Comment: Yes, sir. There are a few. First, exporting might contain a couple thousands of records, i already have 21 columns for this DGV. Second reason is also memory, 'O' will occupy less space than "Open" will. While loading thousands of records, reducing the load is in best interest. What you suggested is surely a good idea when the data load is minimal, I did try a similar workaround too, but it just slows down the application.